# Show a progress bar when using Response.Transmitfile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

On a web forms button click I am doing a simple file download

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(resourcesFolderPath + fileName);        Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
```

As some of the files are quite large anyone know how I can show a progress bar via jQuery / javascript?

Comment: The user's download functionality should be displaying a progress bar, usually by shading the color of the application icon in the taskbar as the progress is made. There really isn't any good way to do this with the client other than using a third-party download manager. The browser does show visual queues though so it's usually best not to re-invent something the browser  already gives you.

Comment: On some devices iPad for example it doesn't so I need a progress bar or some way to show that the file is downloading. I wish iOS just followed normal behaviour but that Apple.

Comment: The problem you have is you can only send one response down to the client per page.  You're already using the response to send the file, as far as I know you can't simultaneously update the page and push a file.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with client code. It's one thing to do it going through the browser to the server since you can use HTML 5 to read and chunk the bytes going to the server. That doesn't work the other way around since any script running on the client side won't know about the data being sent. It can't sit in the middle like you can when uploading.